# angular currency pipe - maxfractiondigits maximum number

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

I'd like to be able to display currencies up to 30 digits after the decimal point (crypto related stuff.. ), but the max I can get out of the currency pipe is 17.

`{{ balance | currency: '':'':'1.2-30' }}`

(same with the number pipe) Is there a maximum for `maxfractiondigits`?
Any suggestions how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is possible. Unfortunately, the numbers have some limitations, but if you only want to display the data, you just need to create your own custom pipe.

See how easy it is to implement and you can use them anywhere in the application just like angular default pipes.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-8gjxkr?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Just remember to declare such a custom pipe in the module (eg. AppModule), and if you want to use it in another module of the application, you must also export it (exports property in the module where you created the pipe). In the case of other modules, it is enough to import the entire module or the pipe itself :)

More info here
https://angular.io/guide/pipes#creating-pipes-for-custom-data-transformations